# How to Not Display A Div if a Cookie Is True?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

Ok, so clearly this doesn't work. I'm just starting out with this cookie business, and I'm fairly new to Javascript as well. This is just a practice site I'm making for fun. Here's what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cutive+Mono' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cookies.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="weusecookies">
    <h1>We Use Cookies</h1>
    <input type="button" value="ok" onclick="ok();"/>
</div>
<script>
var cookiesDiv = document.getElementById("weusecookies");
document.cookie="hasVisited=false; expires=18 Dec 2027 12:00:00 UTC";

if (hasVisited=true) {
    cookiesDiv.remove();
}

function ok() {
    document.cookie="hasVisited=true";
    cookiesDiv.remove();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The primary problem so far is that that initial if statement is triggered right off, and the div disappears the second the page is loaded. How would I fix that? And if I fixed that, would this actually work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should generally not be done with JavaScript - ideally you should use a server-side language to determine if the "hasVisited" cookie has been set, and if not then (and *only* then) should it output the "we use cookies" code.

However, failing this, you could proceed in the opposite direction: have no banner shown (or set it to `display:none`), and have JavaScript *show* the element if the cookie is not set.

... I just noticed the actual problem. `if(hasVisited=true)`. `=` is assignment, and besides you haven't defined the `hasVisited` variable. You need code to read the cookies.